# Can I get access to the database schema project types without having to buy VSTS?

Tags: visual-studio

I'm currently working on an ASP.NET application, and I have downloaded the Visual Studio 2010 Team System beta, which I'm using for my project.

In this version I learned that there is a database schema project. By searching the net I found that this project type also exists for VS 2008, but only in some of the Team System versions. I really learned to appreciate this project type, it really helps out a lot in my database design and development. But the Team System versions are absurdly expensive.

Is there a way to get this project type without having to purchase a Team System license?

It is the only feature of the Team System version that I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Team System Database Edition is available as a separate sku - you don't need the full "Team Suite" to access "data dude", but you will have to pay for it.

The full comparison chart (which feature is in which edition) is [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=727BCFB0-B575-47AB-9FD8-4EE067BB3A37&displaylang=en).

Comment: So there is no way of just adding this project type without paying for at least the Team System Database Edition?

Comment: Bugger. I hope I get my DB schema perfected before the end of the beta then ;)